# How to find equal objects in two Sets in Java in an elegant way? ( Looping sets )

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, set

Say you have to Sets filled with dogs... We want to find out how much weight a Dog has lost after 1 month. So some code here:

```
Set<Dog> dogsJanuary = getDogsInJanuaryFromDB();
Set<Dog> dogsFebruary = getDogsInFebruaryFromDB();
```

Now I need to loop through all the Dog objects and see if a Dog has lost weight. This is how I do it:

```
for(Dog d:dogsJanuary)
    for(Dog g:dogsFebruary)
        if(d.equals(g)) // Assume dog name is unique and equals check if name.equals(name)
            boolean dogLostWeight = compareDogs(d,g)
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Sets.intersection`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#line.638) from guava library.

EDIT, re-using the map idea from musical_coder and the dog name as key:

```
package com.stackoverflow.so21326160;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

public class App {

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Map<String, Dog> dogsJanuary = Maps.uniqueIndex(getDogsInJanuaryFromDB(), ToName.INSTANCE);
        final Map<String, Dog> dogsFebruary = Maps.uniqueIndex(getDogsInFebruaryFromDB(), ToName.INSTANCE);

        final Set<String> commonDogNames = Sets.intersection(dogsJanuary.keySet(), dogsFebruary.keySet());
        for (final String commonDogName : commonDogNames) {
            final Dog january = dogsJanuary.get(commonDogName);
            final Dog february = dogsFebruary.get(commonDogName);
            // use the dogs
        }
    }

    static enum ToName implements Function<Dog, String> {
        INSTANCE;

        @Override
        public String apply(final Dog input)
        {
            return input == null ? null : input.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Can you provide some detail? I do not fully understand what I can do with  Sets.SetView<Dog> intersection?

Comment: @KorayTugay this find the raw common part, so its not suited to your needs, you don't need a way to find equals element, you need a way to iuterate over common element.

Comment: Really thanks for the effort, but it looks like it got more complicated. :) Thanks however..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a primary key that uniquely identifies each `Dog` in the database, use a `Map` to avoid the inner `for` loop:

```
Map<int,Dog> dogsJanuary = getDogsInJanuaryFromDB();
Map<int,Dog> dogsFebruary = getDogsInFebruaryFromDB();

Iterator<Entry<int,Dog>> iter = dogsJanuary.entrySet().iterator();
while( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Entry<int,Dog> entry = iter.next();
    int dog_id = entry.key();
    Dog d = entry.value();
    Dog g = dogsFebruary.get(dog_id);
    boolean dogLostWeight = compareDogs(d,g);
}
```

Comment: I have no control on that level.

Comment: Even you can get data only as Set, you can iterate that set and put it in a Map. It takes linear time.

Answer (score 2):

You can **reduce the complexity** of the loop further if you use an **Ordered Set** like [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). The Ordered Set guarantees the order of the elements in a Set.
This way, you will loop just once over all the elements and you can compare two `Dog` at a given index (*which will be same as the order is changing*) of the set and find the difference in the wait.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simplify this code without writing helper method or using side libraries which will do almost the same what you doing in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If  you could use sorted set and if both the getDogsInJanuaryFromDB() and getDogsInFebruaryFromDB() returns same result, you can go through a one loop and do your operations in that.

Answer (score 0):

You could cut out all of the superfluous dogs from each month before you start, to reduce the number of comparisons that you have to do.

```
Set<Dog> commonDogsJanuary = new HashSet<Dog>(dogsJanuary);
commonDogsJanuary.retainAll(dogsFebruary);

Set<Dog> commonDogsFebruary = new HashSet<Dog>(dogsFebruary);
commonDogsFebruary.retainAll(dogsJanuary);


for (Dog januaryDog : commonDogsJanuary) {
    int januaryWeight = januaryDog.getWeight();
    for (Dog februaryDog : commonDogsFebruary) {
        if (januaryDog.equals(februaryDog) && januaryWeight > februaryDog.getWeight()) {
           // Do whatever
        }

    }
```

}